# Convert date/time using SSIS

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2019

I need to load a txt file into a sql table using SSIS. The column 'Action_date' has dates formatted like this: **Feb 24 2023  9:35AM**. The destination column is data type datetime. It fails with the error: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "Action_date" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.

I tried using the Data Conversion component but get the same result.

[image]

The job fails at the first step before it even gets to the Data Conversion.

[image]

In the Connection Manager I've tried setting the Data Type to string [DT_STR] and various Date types. How can I get this to load to something with a format like this: 2022-12-19 09:57:01.243?

Comment: try_cast('Feb 24 2023 9:35AM' as datetime) results in a valid datetime value - or if the string is invalid it returns NULL  - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TRY_CAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)('Feb 24 2023 9:35AM' as datetime) results in a valid datetime value

To use TRY_CAST() you will need a `Derived Column`:

1. Add a Derived Column transformation to the Data Flow task.
2. Click on the Derived Column transformation to open the editor.
3. In the Expression field include TRY_CAST([columnname] AS DATETIME).
4. Specify the desired output column name.
5. Set the data type of the output column.
6. Save the changes.